# Limitations with Cases in Lightning

Tags: lightning, custom-button, case, visual-workflow

From my understanding there is no 'Close Case' button for Cases in Lightning. Would it be possible to create a custom button that references a flow that could be present at the header along with other standard buttons.  For example the 'Button or Link URL' would be /flow/Close_Case?vRecordId={!Case.Id}.

Comment: have you considered [Create a Close Case Quick Action](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cases_set_up_lex_close_case.htm)?

Comment: Looked into that,  for ease of use and reducing the amount of clicks would essentially want a button that triggers a flow so the reps would just need to click 1 button to close the case as oppose to clicking on the action then clicking save.

Comment: in that case, yes, you can create a lgihtiing component that will invoke a process (or even just udpate the record itself).